# How to pass mulitiple data types in parameters to function?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

F.e. I want to implement inc function:

```
FUNCTION inc RETURNS INT (INPUT-OUTPUT i AS INT, AddExpression AS INT):
  i = i + AddExpression.
END FUNCTION.
```

to use it like this:

```
inc(tt-data.qty,1).
```

I didn't found how to override my function for `DEC` data type or how to combine both in one. If it possible I also want my function to deal with `CHAR` - kind of `ADD-ENTRY`. Maybe this basic functions are already implemented by someone? Something like this [STLib on OEHive](http://www.oehive.org/project/lib).

Comment: The word "unknown" has a specific meaning to Progress 4GL programmers.  It refers to "the unkbnown value" represented by ? and similar to the SQL idea of NULL.  It is a bit confusing here.

Comment: "Unknown type" <> "unknown value". :) Anyway should I write "multiple" instead of "unknown" to avoid confusion?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain old user-defined functions can only have a single signature.  Your function definition is a bit "off".  You are using an input-output parameter (which isn't "wrong" but it is odd) and you aren't returning a value -- which **is** wrong.  It should look like this:

```
function inc returns integer ( input-output i as integer, addExpression as integer ):
  i = i + addExpression.
  return i.
end.
```

Procedures have somewhat more relaxed data-type rules and will do some type conversions automatically (such as an implied decimal to integer conversion).  This would, for example, support passing a decimal that gets automatically rounded:

```
procedure z:

  define input-output parameter i as integer no-undo.
  define input parameter x as integer.

  i = i + x.

  return.

end.
```

You can overload method signatures if you create your function as a method of a class.

Something along these lines (untested):

```
class X:
  method public integer inc( input-output i as integer, input addExpression as integer ):
    i = i + addExpression.
    return i.
  end. 
  method public integer inc( input-output i as integer, input addExpression as character ):
    i = i + integer( addExpression ).
    return i.
  end. 
end.
```

Comment: I love more compact definition and call syntax of functions, I don't really need return value. I keep it in mind when I us them.

Comment: You do need a return value for user-defined functions.  The definition won't compile without it.  More compact is not necessarily better -- obfuscating code does not make it better and, in this case, you are introducing an unexpected side-effect which could easily lead to bugs.  IMHO input-output parameters to functions are a bad practice that should  be discouraged.

Comment: I've got your point Tom, I'll think about it. Anyway it compiles and works on OpenEdge 10.1b. Only warnings appears when I use`RETURN` without return value.

Comment: Hmmmm... I was wrong -- it does compile.  But "works" might be an exaggeration.  Without a return value it returns ?.  Which really isn't the behavior that most people expect from a function.

Comment: In fact I needed a procedure. But procs and funcs are pretty different in ABL, and functions syntax is more useful for me. Off course I would prefer built-in statements like `ADD-ENTRY`, `INC` or smth. But it seems to me that ABL programmers are left to themselves, so I have to do "things". :)